# How do i make a button swap an image with another image using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am very new to Jquery and am trying to learn it, there seems to be a problem with my code, I want it to change an image on button click but the image isn't changing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    $('input').toggle(
      function() {
        $('img').attr('src', '/images/test1.png');
      },
      function() {
        $('img').attr('src', '/images/test2.png');
      }
    );
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input value="change image" type="button" />
  <img src="test1.png" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Toggle is used to Display or hide the matched elements. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: wrap your js in a document ready and check the image source as you change from test1.png to images/test1.png

Comment: @Ethanut, You can make it work using the methods `on` or `click` then have some logic and and set the `src` attribute using `attr`. If its not working post a new question, that way you learn ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1

A script element loads **a single script**.

This can be from code between the start tag and the end tag **or** a URL specified by the `src` attribute.

It cannot load both.

If you provide both (as you are doing) the `src` attribute will be used and the inline script will be ignored.

**You need two script elements**. One to load the jQuery library and one to load your script which uses that library.

## Problem 2

There are no `input` elements in your document **at the time the script runs**. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

---

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('input').toggle(
      function() {
        $('img').attr('src', 'https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals');
      },
      function() {
        $('img').attr('src', 'https://placeimg.com/150/150/people');
      }
    );
  });
</script>
<input value="change image" type="button" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals" />
```

---

## Problem 3

This doesn't look like the behaviour you want ([toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) doesn't toggle between two functions each time something is clicked), and you probably want to be using a click event handler instead.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    const one = 'https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals';
    const two = 'https://placeimg.com/150/150/people';

    $('input').on('click', toggle);

    function toggle() {
      const current = $('img').attr('src');
      $('img').attr('src', current === one ? two : one);
    }
  });
</script>
<input value="change image" type="button" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
} else {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
}
$(this).toggleClass("on");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="xxxxxx_off.jpg" class="img-swap" />
</body>
</html>
```

I think Its work for you.

Comment: "Use this code" — Why? What did you change? Why should it solve the problem? Answers shouldn't be a game of spot the difference.

Comment: `$(".img-swap").live` - http://api.jquery.com/live/ - that method has been deprecated for years and should not be used.

Comment: `<img src="xxxxxx_off.jpg" class="img-swap" />` — Where has the button gone?

Comment: hello Quentin, for image swap in jquery we have to use replace instead of toggle

Comment: in this image, swapping is used so there is no need of a button

Comment: The OP said *I want it to change an image on button click*

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to change your html a little bit and would also suggest to use the .click() event this way (with current src check by 'switch' expression) so it changes the image src on button click.
HTML:

```
<button value="change-image">test</button>
<img id='image' src="/images/test1.png" />
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(
function(){
  switch($('#image').attr('src')){
      case '/images/test1.png':
      $('#image').attr('src', '/images/test2.png');
      break;
      case'/images/test2.png':
      $('#image').attr('src', '/images/test1.png');
      break;
    default:
    //no default action
      break;
  }       
}
);
```

That worked for me.